# NameError in PostsController#create undefined local variable or method `post_params' for #<PostsController:0x007fd289176ae8>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

## Posts Controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def new 
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    if @post.save
     redirect_to @post
    else
     render `new`
   end
 end

  def show
   @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  private

  def post post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
  end   
end
```

Comment: you need edit your question.. add appropriate title, describe in words what you are trying to do, and provide some background to your question.  a code + exception is not a question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here your method name is `post` and it takes an argument `post_params`. But in your code you intend to use `post_params` as the method name.

So change this:

```
def post post_params
 params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
end
```

to:

```
def post_params
 params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a type here:

```
def post post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
end
```

Remove `post`:

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
end
```

Comment: Well it removed my earlier error but now im getting this: 

Missing template posts/show, application/show with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "/Users/Ruben/Desktop/devtips/blog/app/views"

Comment: Create a view for your action `app/views/posts/show.html.erb`.